# Integrating OpenStreetMaps with Cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, leaflet, openlayers, openstreetmap

I was wondering if any of you might have any idea how i can use Open Street Maps(OSM) with cordova? Searching for days now..

All i can conclude is that i am not supposed to directly use OSM's API's as their servers will block me out if i have too many calls.. So there are free open sources names like 
1.Openlayers
2.Leaflet that allow me to use OSM for free.. however i followed all their tutorials but i cant get the map to show up on the emulator..

Im using Visual studios 2015 community edition. And working with Cordova. There is HTML,CSS and JavaScript(jQuery) involved.. But i simply see no map..

---

**Edits 2, 3, 4**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
              integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
              crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
               integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
               crossorigin=""></script>
        <style>
            #mapid { 
                height: 180px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body id="Main">

        <div id="mapid"></div>

        <script>
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={mytoken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            accessToken: 'mytoken'
        }).addTo(mymap);
        </script>

        </body>
</html>
```

This is what i see [image: SS of what i see]

---

**Edits 5, 6**

In Cordova emulator this is what i see [image: Cant display map]

---

**Edit 7**

I have edited the whitelist.. Im guessing it is here cause the only place i can see to add the whitelist in the config.xml is

[image: Whitelist]

---

**Edit 8**

I have also added the CSP as can be seen below
[image]

---

**Edit 9**

So NOW, In my JS file

[image]
1. This is the first image the original file and you can see i have covered my token

[image]
2. So like you said i replaced it with an image from the internetSo i took a pic of an OWL from the internet

[image]
3. I then added it to the CSP

[image]
4. Now i can zoom in and zoom out make the owl tiles become many and few.

The problem i have now is with this:

```
https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/MapID/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=mytoken
```

so i tried to put:

- https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/MapID/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/

IN THE CSP
but still the vector image is not showing :( any ideas now?

Comment: OpenLayers and Leaflet are just javascript frameworks for displaying map tiles and various overlays. They still need to retrieve their map tiles from a tile server. This tile server can be either the official OSM tile server or one of many third-party tile servers. Either way, you need to provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Well basically i just need to show OSM on my cordova app! which i have no idea how to as there isnt any tutorials that show me how to do it on cordova. Could you please guide me on how i can link up Cordova with OSM in any way possible.

Comment: If the map controls are correctly loading but not the tiles (i.e. the basemap remains grey), you probably forgot to _whitelist_ your tile server URL. Debugging with Chrome remote inspector would surely help.

Comment: hey ghybs i appreciate the reply but i just need some help with setting everything up first. Perhaps any online tutorials? i cant seem to find any related to Cordova and OpenStreetMaps :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to mix up things.

As mentioned by @scai, OSM does not provide you with any API when it comes to *raster tiles*.

You just access tiles as plain images:

[image: OSM tile example] <sub>© [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)</sub>

Leaflet (and all other JS mapping libraries like OpenLayers, but also Google Maps) just stitch such tile images together, provide user navigation (panning, zooming) and other functionalities (markers, etc.)

There is nothing specific when integrating such map in a hybrid mobile app using Cordova, *except* for [white listing](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#network-request-whitelist) / [CSP](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy) the Tile Server.

1. Start by making a simple HTML page (without Cordova) with a working Leaflet map.
2. Add a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) (CSP) to tell the browser that you allow the page to fetch [images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src) only from the Tile Server. For example, if you load tiles from OSM at `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, your `<meta>` tag could look like:

```html
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="img-src 'self' https://*.tile.openstreetmap.org/"
>
```

3. **Replace** any CDN resource by local copies. Typically do not load Leaflet from `unpkg.com`. The point of having an installed mobile app is to have as much resources available on the phone storage as possible, and libraries code is typically the thing you do not need to fetch over the air everytime. You can download a copy of all Leaflet assets (CSS, JS, images) on its [download page](http://leafletjs.com/download.html).
4. Copy the page and all its assets into your Cordova project. [Whitelist network requests](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#network-request-whitelist) to the Tile Server (in `config.xml`):

```xml
<access origin="https://*.tile.openstreetmap.org/" />
```

or (unsafe):

```xml
<access origin="*" />
```

If you need further help with CSP and Cordova whitelist plugin, I am certain you can find plenty resources, including here on SO. Obviously, reading through the reference documentation (as linked throughout this post) should be your starting point as well.

BTW OSM [*does* warn](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) that you should not abuse of their tiles, whatever the method through which you access them (including through Leaflet for instance).

Comment: Ok finally i can make it work using a simple HTML page. but it still does not work on Cordova. So I'm guessing like what you mentioned it should be the white listing and CSP. But what exactly do i need to put in there?

Comment: I have added whitelist and CSP but i still don't see the tiles :(

Comment: Could you take a look at my original post ?

Comment: If i download the packages all i see is an empty screen which is worse than using CDN. But that is of secondary issue right now. the main issue is enabling the tiles to display themselves. I tried everything you mentioned. i still cant get it to work *Sighs*

Comment: You should very probably start with a simpler Cordova project (without Leaflet), loading a JS file and displaying an external image. Once you understand how to make it work, you will be able to do the same with Leaflet. Good luck!

Comment: Please take a look at my original post i have managed to load an external image already! but i still cant do it for the normal maps

Comment: Got it to work! it was not even the CSP but the URL.. thanks ghybs cheers